# Filebeat-8.6.2 - Problem with Panw-panos-pipeline ingest pipeline: "field [generated_time] not present as part of path [_temp_.generated_time]"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am hoping there is someone out there who can help me with my problem!

I am trying to process a log file from a Palo Alto firewall and to do that I am trying to take advantage of filebeats and the panw module that ships with 8.6.2.

I can confirm that filebeat is sending the traffic logs to the ingest pipeline but the pipeline  fails to process it on the first "Date" processor which tried to parse a date from a field called "*temp*.generated_time" to be used as the value of @timestamp.

The error message I get is "field [generated_time] not present as part of path [*temp*.generated_time]".

Honestly I am stumped! Is there anyone out there that has run into this kind of problem before?

Cheers,
John

I tried ignoring the failure and the error message from the pipeline goes away (which makes sense) but as before, there are not palo alto specific fields extracted from the log message. It seems this step is crucial for all subsequent steps to work properly.

I can reproduce the error when I try to test the ingest pipeline using a random line from the palo alto log file.

I am expecting/hoping/praying to see all the palo alto specific fields be extracted from the log line so that I may seeing information appearing on the Palo Alto Traffic Dashboard.

Please help!